# Может ли злоумышленник атаковать с разных портов и ip-адресов за короткий промежуток времени?

Tags: firewall

История началась с того, что позвонил в техподдержку провайдера по поводу внезапно упавшей скорости интернета. Технический специалист ответил, что возможно виноваты вирусы или сетевая карта. Я в этом усомнился, сказав, что проверял недавно систему сканером Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool - система чиста. Но все равно проверил опять через AVZ - чисто. Потом решил все таки поставить нормальный файерволл Comodo Firewall (до этого стоял Microsoft Security Essentials - он не имеет файерволла, так как есть брандмауэр windows). Как только я его поставил он мне начал выдавать запросы на разрешение/запрет входящих соединений со странных ip-адресов на порт 445 и 135. Гугл говорит, что ip-адреса из Грузии и Болгарии. Я запретил соединения. То что я пишу ниже, написано после перезагрузки системы. Дело в том, что когда я писал это, антивирус вдруг выдал сообщение, что больше не работает и через несколько секунд система произвольно перезагрузилась. Система до этого момента работала стабильно и такого не наблюдалось. Дополнительная информация:

- Windows 7 SP1 x64
- UAC - включен
- обновление системы включено
- брандмауэр выключен
- система загружена с учетной записью администратора
- антивирус - microsoft security essentials
- файерволл - Comodo Firewall 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атаки из интернета в принципе это обычное дело. Если тебя не целенаправленно взламывают, то можно не заморачиваться. Если б тебя взламывал профи, то он бы столько попыток не делал. Может вирус какой в системе, а антивирь его не видит. Можеть червячок стучиться.

Но по моему это не злоумышленник атакует, это на вашем компе вирус.Этот вирус сканирует выбранные компы(как производится выбор мне не известно) на наличие открытых портов 445(DCOM) и 135(MS_DS) на которых весят виндовые севисы, при нахождении таковых вирус, используя уязвимость данной операционной системы, проникает на комп и начинает производить аналогичные действия с вновь заражённого компа.

Comment: Спасибо. Но паранойя заставила меня удалить MSE + Comodo Firewall. Поставил KIS 2012 (пробный период пока). KIS почему-то упорно молчит. Хотя я поставил в настройках повышенный уровень опасности.

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО

1. для начала воспользоваться [утилиткокой CureIt от DrWEB](http://www.freedrweb.com/cureit/?lng=ru), КРАЙНЕ желательно в безопасном режиме.
2. потом отказаться от Mелко$мягких и "доброго приведения", предположительно, в пользу ESET NOD32.
3. В будущем, опять же сугубо ИМХО, отказаться от творений Mелко$мягких вообще, в пользу той же Ubuntu, например...
4. При наличии возможности для обеспечения безопасности сети от вторжений использовать специализированное ПО, такое как Kerio, на пример... Установить на отдельную машинку в разрез между сетью и модемом/роутером.

ЗЫ Прошу не обвинять в рекламе, все рекомендации - из собственного опыта.